# Can ASP.Net MVC Views (*.aspx) be reused in multiple ASP.net MVC projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to reuse *.aspx files in multiple ASP.Net MVC projects. Is this possible?

EDIT: Anthony's suggestion of using version control system to share common files across multiple projects solves my question in a practical way. Luckily, since I'm using Subversion, the solution fits me. However, if I wasn't using one, how can this problem still be solved?

Is it possible to do something like this?

1. Build a redistributable User Control using VS's website precompilation feature. (As described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2005/10/30/487160.aspx).)
2. Reference the output assemblies in the required projects.
3. Create a modified View engine that instantiates User Controls via generic type parameter.

We then construct controller actions like this:

```
public ActionResult Shared()
{
    return View<SharedPageOrUserControl>();
}
```

Does that look possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally solve this sort of issue via source code control.  Most systems (even VSS) allow you to share a file across multiple projects.

Comment: Yep, that's how I'd probably do it, too - but Sat night is time for architect astronaut to go out and play! +1

Comment: Since I'm using Subversion, I suppose I can just check out *.aspx from a common repository path into each of my projects that requires them. That a neat solution. I suppose I should be doing that for my graphics, css, and js files. Thanks!

Comment: -1; Sharing is something of an anti-pattern for SCM. (Checking in against one of the copies leaves your files in a inconsistent state until you remember to do a get to update the copies).

Comment: @Richard: I don't follow your reasoning the same situation arises when any file is checked in.  This is approach is simple and effective for this scenario.

Answer (score 9):

One idea you could try would be to:

1. Create a project (class library) for your shared Views
2. Add and set any *.aspx markup pages to [Embedded Resources](http://dotnet.org.za/craign/archive/2007/05/05/how-to-access-resources-embedded-in-an-assembly.aspx) in the Properties pane
3. Add a class "EmbeddedViewResult" that inherits from ActionResult - this would contain logic to ensure the embedded .aspx files are extracted and available on disk when called at the end of a controller action.

So in the projects that you wanted to use the shared Views, the controller actions could return something like

```
public ActionResult Shared()
{
    return new EmbeddedViewResult("SharedLib.SharedPage");
}
```

I've done something similar with WebForms pages, so it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried playing around with this solution and ran into two problems: 1.) Class Library projects seems to dislike *.aspx files (missing from the "Add New Item" dialog) and 2.) embedded *.aspx files doesn't seem to be easily editable.

Comment: The "Add New Item" dialog is context sensitive; it doesn't suggest .aspx files since those have no usual relevance in a Class Library Project. But that doesn't mean a Class Library Project cannot contain them.

Comment: Correct, the template is missing; you have to add a text file and rename it. And dealing with embedded resources in this context is a huge pain (rebuilds everywhere)! I had used this technique to package shared administrative pages, and it wasn't fun, but it paid off when used across many apps.